# Most vexing parse confusion

Tags: c++, class, c++11, function-pointers

I'm studying C++11 and I stumbled upon uniform initializers.

I don't understand the following code which should show the "most vexing parse" ambiguity:

```
#include<iostream>
 
class Timer
{
public:
    Timer() {}
};

int main() 
{
    auto dv = Timer(); // What is Timer() ? And what type is dv?
    int time_keeper(Timer()); // This is a function right? And why isn't the argument " Timer (*) ()" ?
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: AFAIK the second line invokes the MVP, the first one doesn't.

Comment: I know that, but I'm confused with the types involved in the code

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here:

```
auto dv = Timer();
```

You have an object of type `Timer` called `dv` that is being copy-initialized from a temporary (the expression on the right side of the `=` sign).

When using `auto` to declare a variable, the type of that variable is the same as the type of the expression that initializes it - not considering cv-qualifiers and references here.

In your case, the expression that initializes `dv` has type `Timer`, and so `dv` has type `Timer`.

Here:

```
int time_keeper(Timer());
```

You declare a function called `time_keeper` that returns an `int` and takes as its input a *pointer* to a function which returns a `Timer` and takes no argument.

> And why isn't the argument `Timer (*) ()` ?

Functions decay to pointers when passed as an argument, so the type of `time_keeper` is actually `int(Timer(*)())`.

To convince yourself, you could try compiling this little program:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct Timer { };
int main()
{
    int time_keeper(Timer());
    static_assert(
        std::is_same<
            decltype(time_keeper), 
            int(Timer(*)())
        >::value, 
        "This should not fire!");
}
```

Here is a [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=1a0332f050cd9aaf1d761e0aba890454-e54ee7a04e4b807da0930236d4cc94dc).

Comment: Thanks, shouldn't the argument be "Timer (*) ()" ? Is "Timer ()" an acceptable function pointer too?

Comment: I guess, that's the case of `functionName` and `&functionName` being the same thing.

Comment: @DavidKernin: Functions automatically decay to pointers when used as function arguments, so `void(Timer())` and `void(Timer(*)())` are identical types.

Comment: To be honest the assertion is thrown with MSVC2012, but I think it's a compiler-related bug.

Comment: @DavidKernin: I believe so. Sounds like an interesting new question for SO :)

Comment: For reference this ambiguity resolution is described in the C++ standard 8.2.1/1 Declarators / Ambiguity Resolution [dcl.ambig.res]

Comment: @AndyProwl: I know the std says this but why allow functions to decay to pointers in function args? It's not exactly intuitive to specify `void(Timer())` to mean `void(Timer(*)())`.

Comment: @ZachSaw: Functions cannot be manipulated as values, only as references or pointers. Think about it, what would you do inside your function with an argument of function type, other than calling it (which is something you can do even if your argument is a pointer or reference to function)? So when you see `Ret(Args...)` (like `Timer()` in this case, where `Args...` is empty) to mean a function's parameter type, the compiler automatically assumes you mean a *pointer* to such a function. Why not a reference? Well, I guess that's because it comes from C, where references don't exist.

Comment: @AndyProwl: I actually meant `void(Timer())` should be a compile error, rather than the compiler implicitly decaying it into a pointer. In which case, `int time_keeper(Timer());` would no longer trigger the most vexing parse problem.

Comment: @ZachSaw: OK, so your point is that `Timer()` should lead to an error when it is used as the type of an argument in a function, but be accepted outside of that context - as in `std::function<Timer()>`. I'm not a compiler expert so I can't really tell whether this "asymmetry" is problematic or not, anyway I'm quite sure the reason why this thing exists in C++ is because of backwards compatibility with C (where there is no such ambiguity, because C does not have constructors).

Comment: @AndyProwl A C compiler is so very different from a C++ compiler. I never understood the need for C++ to be backwards compatible with C. Is it still true that all C codes can be compiled with a C++-only compiler?

Comment: @ZachSaw: There are a few breaking changes in C++, and a few "newer" features of C (C99 or C11) which never became part of C++ (e.g. variable-length arrays), but for the most of it, yes. Take it with a grain of salt though, I'm not a C expert either.

Comment: so I'm confused why either C or C++ allows Timer() as a synonym for Timer(*)() in the parameters...